# Wait 30 sec in Xcode UI Test

Tags: ios, xcode-ui-testing

At a point many web service call is get called. and I just want to wait 30sec, as I know all will finish during this time period. I need a first rough solution.

I tried this, but it raise some error:

```
tablesQuery.buttons["Button"].tap()
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 30.0) {
            let tablesQuery2 = tablesQuery
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: What do you want to check in 30 seconds?

Comment: @AleksandrMedvedev's answer is correct. Your test raises an error because you are dispatching code to run asynchronously, but your test method finishes running before the asynchronous code finishes running. This means that any objects referenced in the asynchronous block may have been cleaned up, which will result in errors. For example, if you try to fulfill a test expectation in an async block of code which ends up running after the test method has returned, an error will be raised.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way is just sleeping the execution for the time being:

```
sleep(30)
```

However, in case you are expecting something to appear, it's better to use [the built-in function](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielement/2879412-waitforexistence) for waiting for existence:

```
element.waitForExistence(30)
```

It doesn't fail if nothing appears, so if it's crucial part of your logic, you probably better to check it via expectation with timer:

```
let exists = NSPredicate(format: "exists == %@", true)
expectationForPredicate(exists, evaluatedWithObject: element, handler: nil)
waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(30, handler: nil)
```